# ctx.fillrect isn't function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I don't know why.

I am using vs 2015

Here is my HTML code

```js
ctx = document.getElementById('screen').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillrect(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="screen" width="1280" height="726"></canvas>
<script src="JAVA/game_setup.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's `fillRect()` not `fillrect()`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Please delete the question

Comment: say an answer to close it i still can't delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fillrect(); "R" in uppercase

Answer (score 1):

You have typo, it's `fillRect` rather than `fillrect`

```js
ctx = document.getElementById('screen').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="screen" width="1280" height="726"></canvas>
<script src="JAVA/game_setup.js"></script>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect)